# É possível um único botão mudar ImageView A para B, C, D... ? - Java/Android

Tags: java, android

É possível o mesmo botão trocar ImageView A para B, C e assim por diante? Em um mesmo onClickListener?

Minha primeira tentativa, já sabendo que não funcionaria foi

```
mNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            escUm.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            escDois.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            escDois.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            escTres.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Também tentei um Handler para aplicar um delay de uma imagem pra outra. Obviamente não era o que eu queria.

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    escTres.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }, 5000); */
```

Alguém sabe como proceder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Até onde entendi ,você quer que ao apertar em um botão o ImageView aja como um "exibidor" de slides.

Para isso você pode usar a classe Timer e TimerTask da seguinte maneira.

Fora do onclick do botão crie um Timer e declara o TimerTask.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task;
```

No onclick você instanciá o TimerTask e faz o seguinte código abaixo.

```
task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Código para a troca de imagens
            }
        });
    }
};
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task ,delay ,período);
```

No código de troca aconselho que você crie uma variável inteira para controlar a imagens e também sugiro que você tome cuidado com esse método pois ele é independente da thread principal (a do aplicativo).

Comment: Entendi... Cara, muito obrigado! Antes eu pensava que esses 'slides' deveriam ser feitos em novas atividades até... Vou seguir sua resposta. Valeu!

Comment: Mas como disse ,tome cuidado pois Timer&TimerTask independem da thread principal ,é possível que mesmo o usuário destruindo a aplicação eles fiquem rodando.